# So I have a sharedobject file (.sol) and need to edit it

Tags: c#, flash

I have a .sol file and I want to edit it but I've noticed that the numbers work like this

```
0x3F, 0xF0 = 1
0x40, 0x00 = 2
0x40, 0x08 = 3
0x40, 0x10 = 4
0x40, 0x14 = 5
0x40, 0x18 = 6
0x40, 0x1C = 7
0x40, 0x20 = 8
0x40, 0x22 = 9
0x40, 0x24 = 10
0x40, 0x26 = 11
0x40, 0x28 = 12
0x40, 0x2A = 13
0x40, 0x2E = 15
0x40, 0x30 = 16
0x40, 0x31 = 17
0x40, 0x32 = 18
0x40, 0x33 = 19
0x40, 0x34 = 20
```

I don't want to have a giant table and it might change once it gets to about 500 so I'd rather want to know how to calculate the number its self from the hex. Anyone got any ideas?

-I'm using this for a gamesave editor so I can't just use a sol editor, I need to know how it's done.

-For future people who **may** come across this post in hope of accomplishing what I tried to do, I decided it was too much of a problem to get the IEEE754 hex format which I'd required, so I ended up making a scraper which did it for me, the numbers go up to 1024. Just add this into a long array http://pastebin.com/9EeYcWq2

Comment: You want us to break the code for you?

Comment: How you noticed that the numbers work like this??

Comment: Basically, I used soledit and got the numbers from there, but I've discovered apart from 0 and 1 everything starts with a 0x40 from there on. So it uses some encoding system LIKE hex, so not necessarily break the code, more or less the right math.

Comment: you can search and find many open source tools which view or edit `sol` files. Look at their code or use one of the libraries.

Comment: I found out the encoding of it - IEEE-754. It took a little digging to find, but thanks for your help though!

Comment: [minerva](http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva) is also pretty decent for editing sol files